# Unable to deploy spring boot project on tomcat 7.0.21 version

Tags: java, tomcat7, spring-boot, jhipster, embedded-tomcat-7

I have deploying maven project on two tomcat version i.e 7.0.21  and 7.0.56.on 7.0.56 version it work fine and on 7.0.21 getting issue.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

This is exception which i am getting while try to run on tomcat version 7.0.21

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/gncnarangwal/appservers/apache-tomcat-7x/webapps/Gobind/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 18, 2015 1:52:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getServletContainerInitializer
SEVERE: The ServletContentInitializer [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci] could not be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1466)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1055)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You're packaging embedded Tomcat in your war file. You can see this in the first line of the exception output that you posted:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/gncnarangwal/appservers/apache-tomcat-7x/webapps/Gobind/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Your Maven configuration looks wrong. You shouldn't be declaring `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. It should be declared in the main `<dependencies>` section of your pom instead. Also, it's recommended that when you're building a WAR with Spring Boot, you mark Tomcat as a provided dependency. This will allow you to run the war file directly or deploy it to a separate container. This would leave you with a pom with `<dependencies>` and `<build>` sections similar to the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```